# C++ Dynamic Array of Objects Sorting by Property

Tags: c++, arrays, class, sorting

I'm trying to implement selection sort as a member function within class, to sort the objects of the class where the number of total players are being got by user input, also the names and scores of the players are being got by user too.

I'll sort the player objects by the property of their scores, which is a class member, being got by user input.

My problem is, i got stuck within the main where i can't call the class' member function sort for the array of objects.

```
class Player{
private:
string name;
int score;

public:
void setStatistics(string, int) // simple setter, not writing the whole function
void sortPrint(int, Player []);
int getScore(){ return score; }
void print(){ cout << name << " " << score << endl; }
};

void Player::sortPrint(int n, Player arr[]){
int i, j, minIndex;
Player tmp;

for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    int maxIndex = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
    {
          if (arr[j].getScore() > arr[minIndex].getScore())
          {
                minIndex = j;
          }
    }

    if (minIndex != i) {
          tmp = arr[i];
          arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
          arr[minIndex] = tmp;
    }

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
arr[i].print(); // not sure with this too
}

}

};

int main(){
int n,score;
string name;

cout << "How many players ?" << endl;
cin >> n;

Player **players;
players = new Player*[n]; 

for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {

cout << "Player's name :" << endl;
cin >> name;
cout << "Player's total score:" << endl;
cin >> score;
players[i] = new Player;
players[i]->setStatistics(name,score); 

}

for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
players->sortPrint(n, players); // error here, dont know how to do this part
}

// returning the memory here, didn't write this part too.

}
```

Comment: What is wrong with `std::sort`?

Comment: Are you doing your own sort for education/fun, or can you use the standard library?

Comment: doing the practice questions from a book, as i didn't come to standart functions, i'm doing by this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `void Player::sortPrint(int n, Player arr[])` with `void Player::sortPrint(int n, Player*)` and call function like `players->sortPrint(n, *players)`

Comment: But it is better to use std containers like std::vector instead of array and use std::sort

Comment: it says expression must have pointer to class type, below the players in main, cant call like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that `players` is a pointer to array of `Player`, and arrays do not have member functions of the containees. As `Player::sortPrint` does not depend on the object itself, declare it as `static` and call it like `Player::sortPrint(n, players);`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a *very* good reason not to, you should use `std::sort` rather than your own sorting algorithm. You should use a comparison function which compares the score of each player.

The following should work in C++03:

```
bool comparePlayerScores(const Player* a, const player* b)
{
    return (a->getScore() < b->getScore());
}


// Returns the players sorted by score, in a new std::vector
std::vector<Player*> getSortedPlayers(Player **players, int num_players)
{
    std::vector<Player*> players_copy(players, players + num_players);
    std::sort(players_copy.begin(), players_copy.end(), comparePlayerScores);
    return players_copy;
}

void printSorted(Player **players, int num_players)
{
    std::vector<Player*> sorted_players = getSortedPlayers(players, num_players);
    // Could use iterators here, omitting for brevity
    for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
        sorted_players[i]->print();
    }
}
```

(Alternatively, you could define an `operator<` on your `Player` class which compares scores, which would let you store players in a `std::set` or `std::map`.)